# Simple click counter with php and js

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, click, counter

Trying to make a very simple counter which updates the value in a mysql database table by 1 each time a user clicks on a link.

```
<a href='http://somesupersite.com' id='246' class='track'>My Link</a>
```

The javascript that should get the id and pass it to the php script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.track').click(function() {
$.post('http://mysupersite.com/sys/tracker.php', {id:this.id});
});
});
```

The php script tracker.php should get the post variable and update the mysql database table column:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$con = mysqli_connect($mysqlHost, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPassword, $mysqlDatabase);
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE id = $id");
```

I don't get any errors but the database does not update either.

Comment: `Var_dump` your query and run it into `Phpmyadmin`

Comment: Can you echo `UPDATE table SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE id = $id` what it print?

Comment: Replace Query Line to mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE id = ".$id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.track').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.post('http://mysupersite.com/sys/tracker.php', {id:this.id}, function(){
            window.location.href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
       });
    });
});
```

Make your link navigate from the success callback of your `$.post()`.

---

The issue seems to me that when you click on the anchor then it just navigates to the `href` provided page, so this might be possible that the ajax is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault()` in the context

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.track').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $.post('http://mysupersite.com/sys/tracker.php', {id:this.id});
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.track').click(function() {
        console.log("here");
        $.post('http://mysupersite.com/sys/tracker.php', {id:this.id});
    });
});
```

When you click the `a` tag, it jumps to the other page. So this function can't work.

If you get the log 'here', it works.